# I must do a demonstration by induction of a sum

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

$\newcommand{\binomial}[2]{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 #1 \\
 #2
\end{array}
\right)}$

I have the following sum : $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binomial{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$

The $\binomial{n}{k}$ is a binomial coefficient with n over k. I must do a proof by induction of this.

I know that I must first show that if I set n=1, then it must be true. But after that what do I do ?

Comment: After the base cases are established, you assume that the identity is true for some $k$ and using that assumption prove that it also holds for $k+1$.

Comment: The base cases ? What is that ? Also, are you saying that I should set n=k ?

Comment: Do you know anything about mathematical induction?

Comment: Not a lot to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the identity is true for $n$ .We'll prove it for $n+1$ .

Use the Pascal identity to split the sum :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k  \binom{n+1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k \left (\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1} \right )=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1) \binom{n}{k}=n 2^{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}=n 2^{n-1}+n 2^{n-1}+2^n=(2n+2)2^{n-1}=(n+1)2^n$$ so the identity holds for all $n$ (for $n=1$ is obvious)

Answer (score 1):

In the easiest proofs by induction, you must assume the formula that must be proved for $n$ and show that it is also true for $n+1$. This is done by writing the LHS for $n+1$, making some algebra to isolate the LHS for $n$ and then substitute.

LHS for $n+1$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\binom{n+1}k$$
Note that this sum has one more term that the one for $n$. Note also that
$$\binom{n+1}k=\binom n{k-1}+\binom nk$$
All this together allow us to write the sum in terms of $n$ instead of $n+1$.

Can you finish?